# Invalid identifier procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql

I'm writing procedure to transfer data from table in one Db named as 'Dev( or testing)' to another table in fdw db where we'll have repository table. Every month, last business day -2, we'll clean data from dev table and transfer it to repository table.
I'm super new to this technology and testing procedure and getting follwiing error

> [Error] ORA-00904 (12: 15):
>   PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "USB"."BAS2_AGENCY_TO_RISKRATE_REPOS"."AS_OF_DATE: invalid identifier

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE USB.Basel2_riskrating
AS 
BEGIN    
    INSERT INTO USB.BAS2_AGENCY_TO_RISKRATE_REPOS@OFSADEV  --INSERTS DATA IN REPOSITORY TABLE
    SELECT *
    FROM   USB.BAS2_AGENCY_TO_RISKRATING_TRAN M 
    WHERE  USB.BAS2_AGENCY_TO_RISKRATE_REPOS.AS_OF_DATE != M.AS_OF_DATE ; --COMPARES DATE COLUMN TO REMOVE DUPLICACY

    COMMIT;

END Basel2_riskrating;
```

Could you please help me in this. Also, it will be great if one could guide me with sample procedure code in wiping data from USB.BAS2_AGENCY_TO_RISKRATING_TRAN table at each month end.

Comment: Probably `AS_OF_DATE` is not in field list, can you post here your DB structure ?

Comment: CREATE TABLE USB.BAS2_AGENCY_TO_RISKRATE_REPOS
(
  AS_OF_DATE       DATE,
-----

Comment: I've created this table and it exist. It was working and I'm not sure what happened and it's not working.

Comment: ```SELECT *
    FROM   USB.BAS2_AGENCY_TO_RISKRATING_TRAN M 
    WHERE  USB.BAS2_AGENCY_TO_RISKRATE_REPOS.AS_OF_DATE != M.AS_OF_DATE ;``` is wrong.

You can not run such a select against DB, it has no BAS2_AGENCY_TO_RISKRATE_REPOS in from clause

Comment: Your `from` clause only refers to a table aliased `m`, so the reference to `USB.BAS2_AGENCY_TO_RISKRATE_REPOS.AS_OF_DATE` is not valid. Perhaps you need a `where not exists` clause instead.

Comment: Can you fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, use `NOT EXISTS`. It's not celar whether you want to check for duplicates in the remote table `usb.bas2_agency_to_riskrate_repos@ofsadev` or a local version of the same. Use the appropriate table inside `NOT EXISTS` to do the comparison.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE usb.basel2_riskrating AS
BEGIN
     INSERT INTO usb.bas2_agency_to_riskrate_repos@ofsadev  
          SELECT * FROM usb.bas2_agency_to_riskrating_tran m
          WHERE NOT EXISTS ( select 1 from 
                               usb.bas2_agency_to_riskrate_repos e --@ofsadev?
                               where e.as_of_date = m.as_of_date
                          );
     COMMIT;  --Try to avoid commits inside procedure, move it to execution section 
END basel2_riskrating;
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM USB.BAS2_AGENCY_TO_RISKRATING_TRAN M WHERE USB.BAS2_AGENCY_TO_RISKRATE_REPOS.AS_OF_DATE != M.AS_OF_DATE ;`

is wrong. You can not run such a select against DB, it has no USB.BAS2_AGENCY_TO_RISKRATE_REPOS in from clause

Comment: INSERT INTO USB.BAS2_AGENCY_TO_RISKRATE_REPOS@OFSADEV --INSERTS DATA IN REPOSITORY TABLE
        SELECT AS_OF_DATE, MOODY, S_AND_P, FITCH, DBRS, RISK_RATING, BAS_RISK_RATING
        FROM USB.BAS2_AGENCY_TO_RISKRATING_TRAN -- SELECTS DATA, TO BE INSERTED, FROM MONTHLY DATA STORAGE TABLE
        WHERE USB.BAS2_AGENCY_TO_RISKRATE_REPOS.AS_OF_DATE != USB.BAS2_AGENCY_TO_RISKRATING_TRAN.AS_OF_DATE ;

Comment: This is the entire code. Basically the goal is: There is table A in warehouse DB and B in production. Before every month end we'll run the procedure to take data from table B and insert it into warehouse DB table A. once it is successful, we'll run another procedure to clear data records in production table B. This part of procedure was for inserting data from production table B to warehouse DB table A.